# How is an android application connected to an Apache server?

Tags: android, apache, xampp

I'm using an android device with a built-in scanner. The custom application it uses, simply gets the corresponding item from a database on my pc. when you scan it and split the information into my point of sale software. To turn it on, I use an Apache server on XAMPP.

I've tried placing the application on my personal phone. However, despite being on the same network the application on my phone (or any other device) returns an error.

I don't know if it's something I need to change/add on localhost, something on my phone, or both.

Comment: Are you using the correct IP (which is the actual ip of your server, not localhost and not the 10.x that Android emulators use)?  Do you have your wifi network set up to allow incoming traffic to that IP and port?  This is almost always a network issue.

Comment: yes @GabeSechan i think i am using the correct ip (ipv4). i already have one operational device, but any other doesn't work, so i'm assuming it's a permissions thing. but what perms and where is beyond me (if it is that).

Comment: This sounds like you're not the developer of that app - Please note what [help/on-topic] has to say about non-development-related questions. If you're the developer of the app, post indication of what goes wrong with code and log output.